# Error in callJMethod(sqlContext, "parquetFile", paths) : Invalid jobj 1. If SparkR was restarted, Spark operations need to be re-executed

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, sparkr

I want to run sparkR on yarn-client through SparkR shell.So I do the like that:

```
./sparkR

sparkR.stop();
sc <- sparkR.init(master="yarn-client",appName="SparkR-Parquet-example2", sparkHome = Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"),sparkExecutorEnv = list(HADOOP_CONF_DIR=”/etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.yarn”,YARN_CONF_DIR=”/etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.yarn”))
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)
path<-"hdfs://year=2015/month=1/day=9"
AppDF <- parquetFile(sqlContext, path)

Error in callJMethod(sqlContext, "parquetFile", paths) : 
Invalid jobj 1. If SparkR was restarted, Spark operations need to be re-executed.
```

I'm new to spark, could anyone help to solve it ?

I'm using spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6

Comment: I am not sure why you need to stop and restart SparkR. You can just pass in the master flag to spark-submit as `--yarn-client` ?

Comment: @ShivaramVenkataraman yes, you're right. In fact, I want to use sparkR in shiny server side. So I want to use the sparkR.init() to initialize a sc for running in cluster

Comment: In that case you can just launch R (or shiny) and follow instructions at https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/R#using-sparkr-from-rstudio -- Could you try to use the same sparkR.init method with this and see if it works ?